# Security on elasticsearch

Tags: security, elasticsearch

With the recent ransomware attacks on elasticsearch, I was wondering what is the good way of securising an elasticsearch instance (available on the web).
I see that there is some ways to enable authentication, and define users and permissions :
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/shield/current/native-realm.html#managing-native-users

Is this suffisant to be protected ?

Thank you

Comment: you can also try https://github.com/floragunncom/search-guard which is open source and basic features are free of charge